# Only join number until hit any latter in python using join

Tags: python-3.x

`string = "buy @ 1890 . 00 and exit $700"`
If the string contains @ then split the string using @. Then take the last split item and only join the number until join hits the letter not the number.

`price  = ''.join(c for c in string.replace(" ","").split("@")[-1] if (c.isdigit() or c=="." ))`

but it retunes 1890.00700, not 1890.00

desire output only 1890.00, not 1890.00700

Comment: Why not split the part after `@` again at `.` or `and`?

Comment: text can be anything but the @ and numbers are constants @mkrieger1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using regex, `re.findall` might work well here:

```py
string = "buy @ 1890 . 00 and exit $700"
nums = re.findall(r'@\s*([0-9. ]+)\b', string)
print(nums)  # ['1890 . 00']
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But I have modified my question. Kindly give a look @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Thanks also I'm thinking that is it possible to use regex in a dynamic way so it can convert all the possible types like 1. @ 1890. 00       2. @ 1890 .00     3.  @1890 . 00  4@ 1890

Comment: My current answer should already be doing this.